# Group multiple child tables by a parent table in a single LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have following tables and relationship between them. I need the result as:
InvoiceId, (WorkDescriptions for that invoice joined by some delimiter), (Sum of Amounts done by PaymentMethod = 'ABC' for that Invoice).

How can I achieve this in a single LINQ Query syntax (not expression/method syntax)?

UPDATE: Note that data in InvoicePayment and InvoiceWorkDescription tables can be empty (scenario where invoice is created but no details are captured yet).

[image]

Comment: Basically you can achieve this by using navigation properties. Since you don't show a class model we can't help you. Neither do you show your own efforts so it's hard to tell where *specifically* you're stuck. The duplicate seems to answer your main question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = 
   from invoice in invoices
   join workDescription in invoiceWorkDescription 
       on invoice.Id equals workDescription.InvoiceId into workDescriptions
   join payment in invoicePayments
       on invoice.Id equals payment.InvoiceId into payments
   select new {
        InvoiceId = invoice.InvoiceId,
        Descriptions = string.Join(", ", workDescriptions.Select(wd => Description),
        TotalPayments = payment.Where(p => p.PaymentMethod == "ABC").Sum(p => p.Amount) }
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are 2 main requirements missing from your solution:
1. See UPDATE in my question below.
2. I need to sum the payment based on some condition and result after applying that condition can be a null result

Comment: I am not sure about 1.  I am not fully understanding the Update.  As for 2.  I have updated my solution.